# Fourier series on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In setting up a Fourier series on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we use that for $l, m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ $$\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}e^{i\langle x, l-m\rangle }=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if }l\neq m \\ (2\pi)^n & \text{ if } l =m.\end{cases}$$

The second case is obvious, but I'm missing how to show the first case. Is it simple as in the $n=1$ case?

Comment: It's a standard calc 2 fact from trigonometric integration.

Comment: @Neal Oh, I see, is it just Fubini's theorem, where we start with whatever component $l_i \neq m_i$? Then this reduces to the 1 variable case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the integral can be Fubinized into 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ix_i(l_i-m_i)} \,dx_i
$$
where $l\ne m$ ensures that at least one of the factors is zero.

Comment: +1 for Fubinized, but you mean *non* zero, right?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Nonzero exponent makes the factor zero.

Comment: Oh, missed the word "factor". Thought you were talking about coordinates.